Can we implement 2FA while running the CI/CD pipeline?
can we implement 2fa while my pipeline (on Jenkins) runs and log in to my server?
Currently, it login with a username/password to my server. Now, I want an extra layer of 2FA. So, is there any mechanism to do this?

Implementation of Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) for Jenkins is feasible. Detailed information regarding this implementation can be accessed through the following link: Documentation on Enhancing Security with 2FA for Jenkins. For installation instructions you can follow this document.

I am not directly using Jenkins all of the time. Like in mobile development dev creates the build automatically by using Jenkins. So, my main purpose is to interact with my server by using 2FA. I know the solution of configuring 2FA on Jenkins.
